# Would a sequence provide any performance gains over SELECT MAX(id)?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am working on re-factoring a database. There is a process that inserts a row in one of two tables, and the id needs to be unique across the two tables.

Currently the application layer iterates through a predetermined array of keys.

I am considering a `Sequence` to generate the next id, as apposed to a `SELECT MAX(id) + 1`.

Are there any performance gains to be realized from using a Sequence?

Comment: Sequences are cached, there'd be no need to go out and grab that max id any longer, which would mean fewer queries, and improvements in throughput (as youd no longer be blocked by grabbing that id). When taking multiple queries that's a huge contention reliever.

Comment: If the two tables require they be on the same sequence of numbers. Then conceptually, are they the same thing? Should they actually be in one table (perhaps with separate tables for additional attributes?
An example would be putting "Call" and "Response" in separate tables, when they are all just "Messages"

Comment: Started going down the one table path, but for reasons too long to detail here, we're staying with two tables.

Answer (score 5):

`SELECT MAX(id)+1;` is incorrect, will not work under even mild concurrency as multiple processes will find the same MAX and then attempt to insert the *same* next value.

A [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) is correct, so by definition better, but not necessarily the best. It should be used as a DEFAULT constraint on the column.

By far simplest solution is to simply use an [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) column.

Comment: can an IDENTITY be shared between 2 tables (as the OP's description)?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Din't catch that. Obviously, not. SEQUENCE still should be used as a DEFAULT constraint, not queried in a round-trip before INSERT.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413383/sequence-as-default-value-for-a-column

Comment: I am refactoring existing tables where the primary key is not an `IDENTITY`. Conceptually I like a `Sequence`, but based on the current the current work load, the performance gain will not be that dramatic.

Answer (score 2):

You could set identity columns to each hop two units, and set one as even numbers and the other as odd. `int identity(1,2)` for one table, `int identity(2,2)` for another table.

Comment: I like this idea for new tables, but I am refactoring existing tables.

Comment: My 2c: This seems very fragile. One operator error (a reseed, or an insert with identity_insert) and you end up with duplicates between the tables.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I agree that SEQUENCE is a better approach in SQL 2012+, but a check constraint to enforce odds/evens could make this approach less fragile and might be worth considering if for some reason you were stuck on SQL 2008 or earlier.